# Angular ngFor error TS2551: Property 'book' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. Did you mean 'books'?

Tags: angular

i would like to do *ngfor pour presenter all the objects in an array, but it always shows that the html can't not find this property in component.ts. it is not a property, it is a class

here are the codes: it is the app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from './common/book';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {


   books : Book[]  =[
               {
                 sku: "text-101",
                 name: "C# crash course",
                 description: "learn C#",
                 unitPrice: 900,
                 imageUrl: "assets/images/books/text-101.png",
                 active: true,
                 unitsInstock:100,
                 createdOn: new Date(),
                 updatedOn: null,
               }, 
               {
                sku: "text-102",
                name: "C crash course",
                description: "learn C",
                unitPrice: 200,
                imageUrl: "assets/images/books/text-101.png",
                active: true,
                unitsInstock:300,
                createdOn: new Date(),
                updatedOn: null,
              }
            ]
}
```

here are the code for the html, here is the problem, you can see that the book below is a class but with component.ts think it is a property.

```
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>



        <tr *ngFor="let book of books"></tr>
        <td>{{book.name}}</td>
        <td>{{book.description}}</td>
        <td>{{book.unitPrice}}</td>
```

and here is the Class Book

```
export class Book {

sku: string;
name: string;
description: string;
unitPrice: number;
imageUrl: string;
active: boolean;
unitsInstock: number;
createdOn: Date;
updatedOn: Date;

}
```

Comment: Is it your complete code? Seems like something is missing. Can you please add screenshot of error?

Comment: src/app/app.component.html:15:15 - error TS2551: Property 'book' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'. Did you mean 'books'?       

15         <td>{{book.unitPrice}}</td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making mistake with ngFor loop, the row should enclose all the data elements.

You want to create the same number of rows as we have objects in an array. We will iterate and enclose all `td` tags inside `tr` (this is HTML convention)

You were getting an error because you used `let book of books` on tr. And in your code `td` elements were outside the `tr` element, so the `book` variable was not accessible.

```
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>

<tr *ngFor="let book of books">
  <td>{{book.name}}</td>
  <td>{{book.description}}</td>
  <td>{{book.unitPrice}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Adding on to your answer, the issue is that the scope of the `book` variable is the `<tr>` tag, outside of that (in `<td>` tags) there is no reference to "book"

Comment: i don't understand that the row shoule enclose all the data elements

Comment: ok, i understand the <td> can not reference the book, so do you have some suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my answer with details and the already added code will fix your issue.